# Как убрать баг после выбора даты?

Tags: javascript, jquery

выбрала начальную дату

покидаю фокус инпута - и календарик скрывается
и дата отправится без конечной

```js
let buttonCancell = {
    content: 'Отмена',
    className: 'custom-button-cancel',
    onClick: (e) => {
    }
}

let buttonOk = {
    content: 'Ок',
    className: 'custom-button-ok',
    onClick: (e) => {
        e.hide();
    }
}


new AirDatepicker('#input', {
    range: true,
    autoClose: false,
    multipleDatesSeparator: ' - ',
     buttons: [buttonCancell, buttonOk]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/air-datepicker@3.0.1/air-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input readonly type="text" id="input" value="15.12.2021 - 18.12.2021">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/air-datepicker@3.0.1/air-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: не ясно на что в сниппете смотреть, с виду все нормально

Comment: @teran , выбираю одну дату и покидаю фокус инпута (она сохранятся). А я должна еще вторую выбрать. Иначе отправится на сервер только начальная дата

Comment: так зачем отправлять форму/запрос, покак обе даты не выбраны?

Comment: @teran ,  вот тут это реализовано уже. Но эта библиотека побольше будет. И не такая гибкая - https://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: в чем у вас проблема перед отправкой (хз что и как вы отправляете) проверить установлена ли вторая дата?

Comment: @teran , да. тоесть что такой формат 26.11.2021 - 30.11.2021.  А не 26.11.2021

Comment: я не уточняю суть происходящего, а спрашиваю в чем заключается сложность проверки введенных значений перед последующей оправкой.

Comment: @teran , там выглядит это как НЕ инпут. Это в корзине просто текст, где есть кнопка редактирования даты

Comment: и что? вы прикручиваете пикер к чему то и можете получить экземпляр (инстанс)  и при отправке получить с него данные. без разницы, инпут там или не инпут.